# Database design problem

Tags: database-design

I have the following structure somewhere in my database[image: database structure]

On all of the levels, there are zero-to-many relationships (i.e. **Job** may have multiple **Documents** which may have multiple **Units** which may have multiple **Translations**).

Without the **Assignment** (which is not there yet - thus the dotted lines) it works pretty well and I feel good about the database design.

Each **Translation** has to be processed by someone (some external contractor). There will be multiple contractors assigned to each job and **Assignment** table is supposed to model these contractor assignments. Basically, an **Assignment** is a partitioning of the **Job**'s **Translations** among the contractors.

Why do I need to store **Assignments** explicitly in the database and not, e.g. directly assign **Contractor** to each **Translation**? Because I need to store some statistics about each assignment.

Few constraints given by the domain:

- a single **Assignment** does not span multiple jobs, if that's not clear from the description (that is, there could as well be **Job** foreign key in the **Assignment** table)
- all **Translations** belonging to the given **Assignment** have the same **Language** (that is, there could as well be **Language** foreign key in the **Assignment**)

What exactly I have problems with?

- How do I enforce these domain constraints?
- I do not know if it is good to have **Job** and **Language** values contained in the **Assignment** entity. Both are uniquely determined by the **Assignment**, so they could be there. This is probably closely related to the first question.

1) If I do not put **Job** and **Language** in **Assignment**, it will make my life more difficult in cases where, for example, I want to list all the assignments for the given **Job** and given **Language** (which I do pretty often).

2) If I put **Job** and **Language** in **Assignment**, it will create a cycle in the schema (**Job** -> **Assignment** -> **Translation** -> **Unit** -> **Document** -> **Job**) and necessity of an additional constraint: for each **Assignment**, its **Language** must be the same as the **Language** of all of its **Translations**, the same for **Job**

How would you tackle this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The smallest chunk of a document is a unit? What is the smallest unit of work that one contractor can get?

Comment: @Damir Yes, **document** consists of **units** (basically text in source language) which consist of **translations** (which differ by target language to which the contractor has to translate the source text). The smallest possible unit of work for a contractor is a single **translation**.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I guess, most of this should be obvious, just note that each unit can be given to several contractors for translation -- if one should fail, or in parallel. `TranslationAssignmentNo` can be `{1,2,3..}` for each `UnitTranslation` -- in most cases it would be `1`.

**EDIT**

Maybe it would be better to move job to be collection of `UnitTranslations` so that a new job may be opened in future if the same document needs to be translated into new language.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think your model does not reflect my domain entirely. As you noted, in this model single **UnitTranslation** may be assigned to more contractors. This is not allowed in reality. The assignments do not overlap in this sense. That is, while in your model the tuple (`DocumentID, DocumentUnitNo, TargetLanguageID, TranslationAssignmentNo`) uniquely determines an assignment, in fact it is (`DocumentID, DocumentUnitNo, TargetLanguageID`) which determines it.

Comment: By the way, would you tell me please which tool do you use to create these nice-looking diagrams?